# Problem writing struct to file

Tags: c

I have a problem with a function which should write a struct to a file, the files are created however they stay empty whatever I do.

This is the struct that I'm trying to write to the file:

```
typedef struct
{
    double dA;
    double dA1;
    double dB;
    double dB1;
    double dAwnser;
    char cStepOne[24];
    char cStepTwo[24];
    char cStepThree[20];
    char cFormula[26];
} equationData_t;
equationData_t equation;
```

This is the function to write the struct to a file:

```
void writeDataToFile(equation)
{
    int iSizeOfStruct = 0;
    char cFileName[20];
    int iQuitProgram = 0;
    iSizeOfStruct = sizeof(equationData_t);
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Give file name with extension (Max 20 char.):\n:");
        scanf("%s",&cFileName[0]);
        pnf = fopen(cFileName, "r+");
        if (pnf == NULL)
        {
            printf ("\nError: File not found!\n1.Try again.\n2.Quit.\n3.Make new file.\n:");
            scanf("%d",&iQuitProgram);

            switch(iQuitProgram)
            {
                 case 1: break;
                 case 2: exit(1);
                 case 3: makeNewFile();
            }

         }
         if (pnf != NULL)
         {
            printf("\n************************************\nFile opend!\nWriting data to file.\n");
            fwrite(equation, iSizeOfStruct, 1, pnf);
            fclose(pnf);
            printf("Data written");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the real code. The parameter named `equation` has no type. And so that code is quite clearly not valid.

Comment: This is the "real" code, I can give you the "whole" code, all of the 275 lines but I can't make it more real.....

Comment: Can you explain how `void writeDataToFile(equation)` compiles? Parameters have types and names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use open() and then pwrite() instead of fopen() and the fwrite().

However, in your code:

```
fwrite(equation, iSizeOfStruct, 1, pnf);
```

should be modified in:

```
fwrite(&equation, iSizeOfStruct, 1, pnf);
```

Comment: How can you possibly say that when you don't know what type `equation` is? The compiler is obviously happy that it is a pointer and convertible to `void*`.

Comment: I'm just guessing, since the struct is defined as typedef equationData_t equation;

Comment: FWIW I was about to post the same answer.  `equation` is of type `equationData_t` defined in the upper code block.

Comment: @Cheeseminer No, I'm talking about the parameter to the function.

Comment: The compiler gave an error if I added type struct before equation so I removed it, adding & worked, I looked over that. Is there any way to save the data to a file where it is readable from notepad?

Comment: If you want something readable from notepad, you shouldn't be dumping raw data structures, but formatting the data into text yourself.

Dumping raw data is usually a bad idea, because reading it in again will be difficult whenever you or the compiler reorganize the structure.